# Android Notification Intent Not launching the said Activity and Notification Sound Issue

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

Hi i am working on an app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging and i am trying to show notification when app receives a message using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

 **When App is Running**

1. i can hear notification sound
2. when i tap on notification it gets me to the correct activity in my case **NotificationActivity.java**

**Now when App is closed not running in background (these are the main issues that need to be resolved and need explanation for this unnatural behaviour)**

1. I can see the notification but cannot hear notification sound.
2. when i tap on notification it doesn't opens **NotificationActivity.java** but opens **Splash.java** which is default/launcher activity

Below are the Code Snippets.

Mainfest.xml

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Dashboard"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard" />

        <activity android:name="pk.edu.kiu.jobslocatoer.NotificationActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="pk.edu.kiu.jobslocatoer.MESSAGING_ACTIVTY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".receivers.NotificationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="pk.edu.kiu.jobslocatoer.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"></activity>

        <service android:name=".services.MessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".services.InstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


    </application>
```

**NotificationReceiver.java**

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent notify = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), notify, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Titile")
                .setContentText("Text")
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify((int) SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), notification);
    }
}
```

**MessagingService.java**

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(GlobalConfig.TAG, GlobalConfig.getRef(this) + " notificaiton: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("pk.edu.kiu.jobslocatoer.MESSAGING_EVENT"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firebase Notification**

1.If you are sending notification through firebase console,firebase will add a notification object to your message like this

```
{
   //..
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "message body sample text",
      "title" : "notification Tittle",
      "icon" : "icon information sample"
    }
   //..
  }
```

1) If your notification contains this *notification payload* and If your app is in *background* then,

- The notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.

2) If your notification contains this *notification payload* + *data payload* and If your app is in *background* then,

- The notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

3) If your notification contains only *data payload*(`{data" : {"body" : "message body sample text","title" : "notification Tittle","icon" : "icon information sample"}`) and If your app is in *background* or *foreground*  then,

- OnMessageReceived() method of Firebase Message Handler get called and we can write code to show notification in this method.

So If you want to execute `OnMessageReceived()` method everytime when you get a notification,then from server side you should always pass only *data payload*.Otherwise `OnMessageReceived()` will not be executed and Firebase will handle the notification showing thing.

Comment: sorry that not the question i asked, i am not having issues with FCM i am having issues about the activity and notification sound behaviour

Comment: that is right answer actually, after reading the whole documentation and analysis of the application state. any one who want to see more detail please also consult the documentation for better understanding.https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 2):

```
Use this code:    
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
           NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
           if (bitmaplogo != null) {
               notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(bitmaplogo);
           } else {
               notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
           }
           if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
               notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_transparent);
           } else {
               notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon);
           }
           notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
           notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
           notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody);
           notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody));
           notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
           notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
           notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

           int num = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
           NotificationManager notificationManager =
                   (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           notificationManager.notify(num, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Sorry this also not work and  you didn't write how you created pending intent? as far i know the problem is with Intent and PendingIntent

Answer (score 1):

```
 Intent resultIntent = null;

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentText(message);




        resultIntent = new Intent(context,Activity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Activity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        5,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(pushId, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```